# Excel “power of” function to JS

Tags: javascript, excel, pow

can you please help to me, my excel function is

`=(C27*((1+((C28*100)/1200))-1))/(1-((1+((C28*100)/1200))^(-C29*12)))`

how to write it on java script

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `^` with [exponentiation `**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation) the operator for [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

```
=(C27*((1+((C28*100)/1200))-1))/(1-((1+((C28*100)/1200))**(-C29*12)))
```

Comment: please check this http://www.mruncommon.com/MYTEMP/excel/excell.PNG

Comment: what should i see there?